# The users input can't save to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
<ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="lbldescription" runat="server" width="175px"   Text='<%#Eval("description") %>'/>
 </ItemTemplate>
 <EditItemTemplate>
     
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtdescription" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 </EditItemTemplate>



protected void gvManage_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        string topicID = gvtopic.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["topicID"].ToString();
        TextBox description = (TextBox)gvtopic.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtdescription");
        string sql = "Update topic SET description=@description WHERE topicID= @topicID";
        var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);


        con.Open();

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@topicID",topicID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", description);
       

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();


        gvtopic.EditIndex = -1;
        GVbind();
    }
```

I'm using the gridview to display the description and let users edit and update it. But the user's input(they enter at textbox) won't save to the database. No matter what the users type in the textbox, the text "System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox" will be saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is passing a [TextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox?view=netframework-4.8) instance as a parameter to the query, not the textbox's contents. [AddWithValue](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlParameterCollection_AddWithValue.htm) "helpfully" tries to convert any type it doesn't understand into text by calling its `ToString()` method.

`TextBox` doesn't overload `ToString()` though, so the default [Object.ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netcore-3.1) method is used instead, which returns the type name, `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox`.

To pass the contents, use [TextBox.Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.text?view=netframework-4.8) :

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", description.Text);
```